# How to Rename and Have Colored Lores

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want it to have color. Like a diamond here. I really don't know what to do. Like do I use `tellraw` like "color":"red" or what? Do I use `&a` stuff? I haven't ever used a command with a name/lore.

I am trying to make deathrun but one thing is the reward I need which is the Diamond with name that they can change into items like shopkeepers plugin, yes it's mine, but right now I am just using command blocks and I have this 4 second before re-fill issue and deathrun 
is quite hard to make. I just need how to get color into that name all I need.

NOTE: Its a Minehut server, there are certain plugins I can have and not have.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I'm afraid it's very unclear what you're asking.  You should consider presenting your sentences in a clearer, more formalized manner in order to help the readers understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

### Install [AnvilColors](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/anvil-colors)

This plugin allows you to rename items in an anvil using [color codes and formatting.](https://wiki.ess3.net/mc/)
You can also use `/addlore <text>` and `/removelore <line number>`, which support formatting as well, to customize the item.

Comment: Cant, its a minehut server. There is no such thing.